# Laplace transform simplification

Tags: derivatives, laplace-transform, distribution-theory

If $w$ is input signal and $t$ time. How come the following holds? $$ L(tw) = -L'(w)$$

I dont understand this at all. Could this be due to some kind of distribution quirk of the two-sided Laplacetransform that I am not aware of?

Comment: Where did you find this weird notation?

Comment: @K.defaoite In my old examsbook (not english) here is a screenshot of the page: https://imgur.com/MIaZdFV

Answer (score 1):

Pending your response on the strange notation, I will assume you mean the property $t * f(t) \to - \frac{d F(s)}{ds} $, where $F(s)$ denotes the Laplace transform of $f(t)$.

Recall the definition of the Laplace transform,
$$
F(s) \equiv \mathcal{L}(f(t)) = \int_0^{\infty} f(t) e^{-st} dt
$$
Supplying $f(t) = t f(t)$ into the definition, we have
$$
\int_0^{\infty} tf(t) e^{-st} dt.
$$
Let us use the definition of $\mathcal{L}(f(t))$ and differentiate by $s$ to see that
$$
\frac{d}{ds} F(s) = \frac{d}{ds} \int_0^{\infty} f(t) e^{-st} dt = \int_0^{\infty} 
 \frac{\partial}{\partial s} f(t) e^{-st} dt = \int_0^{\infty} 
 - tf(t) e^{-st} dt = - \mathcal{L}(tf(t))
$$
Collecting left and right hand sides and rearranging we see $\mathcal{L}(tf(t)) = -\frac{d}{ds} \mathcal{L}(f(t))$, which I believe is the same as your notation of $L(tw) = -L'(w)$.